# Is it possible to sample HE ciphertexts using pseudo-random generator?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, pseudo-random-generator, chosen-plaintext-attack

I'm trying to sample HE ciphertexts which serve as ciphertexts encrypting some random values. I have realized a example program using Microsoft SEAL, which implements a variant of BFV scheme. Unfortunately, the ''noise budget'' of these uniformly-distributed ciphertexts is zero and thus they cannot support any further homomorphic evaluation. However, when I draw these ciphertexts from discrete Guassian distribution (with mean = 0), they have non-zero ''noise budget'' and work fine.

I'm quite confused about this result. Since BFV scheme is IND-CPA secure, its valid fresh ciphertexts should be indistinguishable from malformed ones (i.e., drawn from uniform distribution). However, the experiment result shows that a uniformly-distributed ciphertext does not form a valid ciphertext of BFV scheme with overwhelming probability.

Is there something wrong? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since BFV scheme is IND-CPA secure, its valid fresh ciphertexts should be indistinguishable from malformed ones (i.e., drawn from uniform distribution).

IND-CPA says that someone *who doesn't know the secret key* cannot distinguish those two distributions.

> However, the experiment result shows that a uniformly-distributed ciphertext does not form a valid ciphertext of BFV scheme

You can only check whether a ciphertext is "valid" if you have the secret key. So there is no contradiction.

An analogy is a length-doubling PRG $G: \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^{2n}$. The output of the PRG is indistinguishable from the uniform distribution over $\{0,1\}^{2n}$. That doesn't mean that most strings in $\{0,1\}^{2n}$ are "valid outputs" of the PRG. In fact, only a negligible fraction ($2^n$ out of $2^{2n}$) of them are.